# Strange opacity change on hover only appearing in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, hover, opacity

I´m testing my newest design and there is one specific issue I cannot figure out.

It appears that a specifik element is triggering an opacity change when I hover the element.
According to my tests this only occurs in Firefox and IE. It doesn´t happen in Chrome.

My best guess is that this is happening due to some sort of browser specific CSS but I have not been able to locate any CSS on any of the elements that is causing this opacity change.

One of the problems is also that I normally use Chrome F12 when I need to spot source code issues and hover CSS effects are hard for me to locate in Firefox and Chrome.

Here is a link to my test-site where you can see the problem in Firefox and IE when you for instance open the accordeon tab "Vælg Stof Indvendig" and hover the images:
http://www.geniusdesign.dk/Demoer/Tailoredsuits/design-dit-eget-jakkesaet/design-selv-jakkesaet-detaljer

Comment: I dont see any accordian tab.. page asking for login

Comment: link is upadting or so, requires login

Comment: Sry about that. I have now updated the link to the correct address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have css that says the following: `.product-field-display:hover { opacity: 0.5; }`

Because the `.product-field-display` element is a span wrapping div's, Chrome is basically making it a non-element (height/width of 0 and no placement on the page). But Firefox is still reacting to it (I guess IE is too).

Comment: it's in templateOLD.css on line 2601.

Comment: That´s it! Problem solved. I have no clue how I missed that.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your site, but have you used a reset at the top of your CSS? This usually solves problems like this. Some browsers s=do weird things by default!

Comment: Yea, I have loaded a reset script in the template, and still the same issue.